# Spawn e2big node

Tags: node.js, debian, parameter-passing, exec, argmax

I have a node server that runs on debian and I'm trying to pass data extracted from a file into the command line using `exec()`.

```
getconf ARG_MAX = 2097152 bytes (2 mb)

myFile = 600 kb (contains 600kb worth of parameters)
```

When I call exec() command from node:

> Error: spawn E2BIG
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:372:11)
>       at spawn (child_process.js:543:9)
>       at Object.execFile (child_process.js:221:15)
>       at exec (child_process.js:152:18)
>       at Promise (child_process.js:160:15)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at args (child_process.js:159:12)

Shouldn't it work since `getconf ARG_MAX` is bigger than the data I'm trying to pass?